# Why can't I run linspace() through my python generator? (Beginner)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

My function uses a method to calculate the coefficients for a cubic equation, and then runs through a for loop and yields. I then iterate through it with another for loop outside the function to call it and make a list of the roots from the cubic equation.

I can run it when I input scalar values, but when I put one of the variables as a sequence with `np.linspace()` it outputs `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Here is my code:

```
Tlnh = np.linspace(18,100,10)
Tch = 33.145 #K
Pch = 1.2964 #MPa
Dch = 31.263 #kg/m3
wh = -0.219 
 
def root((T,P,Tc,Pc,w, R=8.314):
      .
      .
      .

      #Using np.roots() and only printing out the real positive number
      coeff = [1,p1, p2, p3]
      roots = np.roots(coeff)

      #prints out the real positive roots only. 
      for i in range(len(roots)):
          if np.isreal(roots[i]):
          return np.real(roots[i]) 

      return 

g = [h for h in root(Tlnh,p1h,Tch,Pch,wh)]
```

Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-4b4a96b379ea> in <module>
      1 #Hydrogen Densities for Pr = 0.8
      2 #r =[h for h in root(Tlnh,p1h,Tch,Pch)]
----> 3 g = [h for h in root(Tlnh,p1h,Tch,Pch,wh)]
      4 print(g)

<ipython-input-76-20726dad64bd> in root(T, P, Tc, Pc, w, R)
     44     #Using np.roots() and only printing out the real positive number
     45     coeff = [1,p1, p2, p3]
---> 46     roots = np.roots(coeff)
     47 
     48     #prints out the real positive roots only.

<__array_function__ internals> in roots(*args, **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in roots(p)
    220 
    221     # find non-zero array entries
--> 222     non_zero = NX.nonzero(NX.ravel(p))[0]
    223 
    224     # Return an empty array if polynomial is all zeros

<__array_function__ internals> in nonzero(*args, **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in nonzero(a)
   1906 
   1907     """
-> 1908     return _wrapfunc(a, 'nonzero')
   1909 
   1910 

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(
```

)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: `np.roots` is the problematic call - since it expects a 1d array of coefficient. Each coefficient must be a number, not an array.

Original answer for reference:

> The problem is most probably in the line:
>
> ```
> if np.isreal(...):
> ```
>
> (in theory, you should have gotten a traceback pinpointing the line).
>
> But why? Well, the function gives you something like:
>
> ```
> if [True, False, False, True, ....]:
> ```
>
> Now how should the `if` operator interpret this result? Is it True
> or False? Answer: It gives up and throws you the error you observed.

Comment: The error did include a traceback, but for some many beginners don't think it's relevant - for us or for themselves.

Comment: Am I able encapsulate everything inside the function within a for loop, so that it runs and calculates from the linspace() function one-by-one?